# Understanding RASA Forms

Tags: rasa-nlu, rasa, rasa-core

#### My goal:

I'm trying to implement a simple report rule using [Forms](https://rasa.com/docs/rasa/forms/) for my RASA Assistant, which should work as following:

```yaml
User: "I want to report something."
Assistant: "Please describe your problem in the following message."
User: <short description of problem>
Assistant: "Thank you for report."
```

I expect, that whole report message from user will be saved as a text (string) in `report_message` slot and that's also my main goal. I followed an official RASA documentation and probably missed something important or made a bug somewhere and I can't find out, what I did wrong.

#### Current State:

Current implementation works like this:

```yaml
User: "I want to report something."
Assistant: "Thank you for report."
```

Assistant completely ignores `utter_ask_report_message` and `report_message` slot is filled with text content of my `report` intent - `I want to report something.`.

#### My RASA project files:

**nlu.yml**

```yaml
version: "2.0"

nlu:
  - intent: report
    examples: |
      - I want to report something.
      - I want to report a problem.
      - I want to report a bug.
      - #report
```

**rules.yml**

```yaml
version: "2.0"

rules:
  - rule: Activate report_message_form
    steps:
      - intent: report
      - action: report_message_form
      - active_loop: report_message_form

  - rule: Submit report_message_form
    condition:
      - active_loop: report_message_form
    steps:
      - action: report_message_form
      - active_loop: null
      - slot_was_set:
          - requested_slot: null
      - action: utter_success_report_message_form
```

**domain.yml**

```yaml
version: "2.0"

actions:
  - validate_report_message_form

intents:
  - report

entities:
  - report_message

slots:
  report_message:
    type: text

forms:
  report_message_form:
    report_message:
      - type: from_text
        intent: report

responses:
  utter_ask_report_message:
    - text: "Please describe your problem in the following message."

  utter_success_report_message_form:
    - text: "Thank you for report."
```

**actions.py**

```py
from typing import Dict, Text, List, Optional, Any

from rasa_sdk import Tracker
from rasa_sdk.executor import CollectingDispatcher
from rasa_sdk.forms import FormValidationAction
from rasa_sdk.types import DomainDict


class ValidateReportMessageForm(FormValidationAction):
    def name(self) -> Text:
        return "validate_report_message_form"

    async def required_slots(
        self,
        slots_mapped_in_domain: List[Text],
        dispatcher: CollectingDispatcher,
        tracker: Tracker,
        domain: DomainDict
    ) -> Optional[List[Text]]:
        return slots_mapped_in_domain + ["report_message"]

    async def extract_report_message(
        self,
        dispatcher: CollectingDispatcher,
        tracker: Tracker,
        domain: Dict
    ) -> Dict[Text, Any]:
        text_of_last_user_message = tracker.latest_message.get("text")
        return {"report_message": text_of_last_user_message}
```

Thanks for every help and suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thie issue is your implementation of `validate_report_message_form`. This action is also called during the activation of your form which means that `extract_report_message` will fill it with the text of the message which activates the form.  You can fix that by adding a check of `if tracker.slots["requested_slot"] == "report_message"` to ensure to only set this slot when Rasa Open Source requested the user to fill the slot.

```py
from typing import Dict, Text, List, Optional, Any

from rasa_sdk import Tracker
from rasa_sdk.executor import CollectingDispatcher
from rasa_sdk.forms import FormValidationAction
from rasa_sdk.types import DomainDict


class ValidateReportMessageForm(FormValidationAction):
    def name(self) -> Text:
        return "validate_report_message_form"

    async def required_slots(
        self,
        slots_mapped_in_domain: List[Text],
        dispatcher: CollectingDispatcher,
        tracker: Tracker,
        domain: DomainDict
    ) -> Optional[List[Text]]:
        return slots_mapped_in_domain + ["report_message"]

    async def extract_report_message(
        self,
        dispatcher: CollectingDispatcher,
        tracker: Tracker,
        domain: Dict
    ) -> Dict[Text, Any]:
        if not tracker.slots["requested_slot"] == "report_message":
          return {}

        text_of_last_user_message = tracker.latest_message.get("text")
        return {"report_message": text_of_last_user_message}
```

Comment: Solved my problem. Thank you. :)